# How can I detect a new blog post using mechanize in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, screen-scraping, mechanize, blogs

I am try detect when a new blog post has been added to a blog. I am using mechanize for the scraping. Currently this is straight forward if you know the parent tags of a blog `<article><header><h1>Blot Title here</h1></header></article>` you can just do a diff of the titles you have now to the last time you checked. But I want to do this programatically. Is there a way to programmatically know what section or tags of a page that holds the titles of the blog posts without explicitly giving the heirachy of tags to the script?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is a blog name blog.example.com. There are the post -

```
<article><header><h1>Blot Title here1</h1></header></article>
<article><header><h1>Blot Title here2</h1></header></article>
<article><header><h1>Blot Title here3</h1></header></article>
```

Using [selector Gaget](http://selectorgadget.com/) you will get an idea which css is responsible for the each article. To scrap the article you can use nokogiri or machanize gem.

Suppose macanize bot will visit blog.example.com and it will collect all the article and insert into your database.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
if 1==1
url = "http://www.eslemployment.com/country/esl-jobs-Vietnam.html"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
data = []
doc.css("#joblist td:nth-child(1) a").first(5).each do |titlecss|
country = "8"
jobtype = "1"
urlnext = titlecss.attr('href')
docnext = Nokogiri::HTML(open(urlnext))
docnext.css('#jobdescription div').remove
docnext.css('#detailjob , #job-summary').each do |detailscss|
docnext.css('#pagemsg h1').each do |titlenextcss|
data << JobPost.create(
:title => titlenextcss.text,
:jobslink => urlnext,
:description => detailscss.inner_html,
:country_id => country,
:job_type_id => jobtype
)
end
end
end
end
```

Here is a example of nokogiri gem. It collect the jobs from www.eslemployment.com . Now your question is how you can detected new article has added.

This code collect all the jobs from a page and added it into the database. I use here "distint" code into the model for this reason only new job will added to the database. no duplication job will added into the database. When new Jobs is added you can make a notification which job is added.

This is not effecient way. But it will work. Otherwise you can use the rss feed of that blog. This is the proper way to detect new post.